# Non-blocking /dev/hidrawX reading with asyncio in Linux

Tags: python-3.x, embedded-linux, python-asyncio, keyboard-events

what is the right spell to do something like:

```
async def read(fd):
    return fd.readline()

with open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb') as fd:
     while True:
         line = await read(fd)
         if line is None:
             break
         consume(line)
```

I need to poll /dev/hidrawX from a program built around asyncio.
How can I do it in non-blocking fashion?

I would like to avoid to go the `/dev/input/eventXX` way with all associated conversion problems (and also because I tried and events are lost in transit)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `hidraw0`, but if it supports file reading interface, easiest way is probably to use [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles#aiofiles-file-support-for-asyncio). It uses thread under the hood anyway so I think it should work fine.